# Best way to update 10k rows based on ID

Tags: mysql

We have a table clients (1m rows)

```
CREATE TABLE `clients` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `external_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `clients_3_index` (`status`,`client_id`,`external_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=717651
```

On the backend, we regularly request an API that returns a list of external_ids. The list contains around 10k external_ids. If an external_id is new, we insert it as a new row to the table clients with status 1.

If an external_id disappeared from the list, we have to change its status to 0. Meaning, any external_id that is **not** in that list needs to be updated to status 0 in case it still has status 1. What is the best way to do that?

We currently do it like this

```
UPDATE clients SET status = 0 WHERE status = 1 AND client_id = 2 AND external_id NOT IN (12540726, 12540725, 12540720, 12540719, 12540717, 12540716, 12540712, 12540711, 12540706, ...)
```

The **NOT IN** contains the 10k items from the API response.
It is running around 180s (which is way too long)

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE status = 1 AND client_id = 2 AND external_id NOT IN (12540726, 12540725, 12540720, 12540719, 12540717, 12540716, 12540712, 12540711, 12540706, ...)
```

This is running 0.01s

Why is the SELECT so much faster than the UPDATE? The query is updating between 0 to 100 rows, which should not take that long. Is there a better way to do it?

Our MySQL Version is 8.0.28

edit:
One alternative approach would be letting the backend handle the logic. So each time we have to update:

1. `SELECT external_id FROM clients WHERE client_id = 2 AND status = 1`
2. Letting the backend compare the list of 10k external_ids with the result from the query above. Any external_id that is in the query but not in the list needs to be updated in the next step
3. `UPDATE clients SET status = 0 WHERE client_id = 2 AND external_id IN (123, 456, 789, ...)`
   As we now know which external_ids have to be updated, we can UPDATE these external_ids specifically instead of updating all external_ids NOT IN the main list

Would this be a better approach?

Comment: Does it get progressively slower with higher numbers of items in the `IN` clause, or is it just plain slow regardless?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the result of `EXPLAIN ...` for both the `UPDATE` and `SELECT` queries.

Comment: I think the problem is that `status` is the first column in the index. So the index B-tree is being totally rewritten for all those rows.

Comment: Let's discuss _why_ the application needs to change 10K rows.  There _may_ be a way to avoid the Update completely.  Meanwhile, [chunking](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks) the Update solves some problems.